# Creating external hive table from dynamodb table in sparkSQL 2.2.1

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am having issues to execute the following hive query from sparkSQL 2.2.1. The query works fine in the hive editor in hue. I have loaded the jars (emr-dynamodb-hadoop-4.2.0.jar and emr-dynamodb-hive-4.2.0.jar) for dynamodb.

The problem appear to be in the syntax. I have tried to use [this](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html) but no luck.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema.table 
(name string, surname string, address string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
"dynamodb.table.name" = "dynamodb-table", 
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "name:name,surname:surname,address:address"
);
```

I was able to run this:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS surge.threshold3 (name string, surname string, address string) USING hive
OPTIONS(
        INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat',
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat'
)
TBLPROPERTIES (
        "dynamodb.table.name" = "dynamodb-table", 
        "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "name:name,surname:surname,address:address"
)
LOCATION ''
```

However, I can't find a way to find the location of the dynamodb table. Its quite different from locating hdfs or s3.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Assumably whatever AWS keys you're using, all Dynamo tables are just named under that account. There is no "disk location", so having an external table doesn't make much sense

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't get why it does not make much sense. According to aws its feasible: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.ExternalTableForDDB.html

Comment: What I meant was `CREATE TABLE...  LOCATION` doesn't